# Android studio could not find class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I work on a project original from eclipse and imported to Android Studio 1.3. I am experiencing these two errors:

```
08-16 12:35:19.790    4091-4091/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.jmm.ipassion.Utils$1', referenced from method com.jmm.ipassion.Utils.registerGCM

08-16 12:35:19.790    4091-4091/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.jmm.ipassion.Utils$2', referenced from method com.jmm.ipassion.Utils.startAnimationButton
```

No errors before I deploy to a phone for debugging.

My gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jmm.ipassion"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':androidUniversalImageLoadermaster')
    compile project(':mixpanelandroid')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

And my `utils.java` looks like this:

```
08-16 12:35:19.810    4091-4091/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jmm.ipassion, PID: 4091
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nmd.libs.UtilityMain
        at com.jmm.ipassion.Utils.upLog(Utils.java:60)
        at   com.jmm.ipassion.BaseApplication.onCreate(BaseApplication.java:103)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4749)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The function in `utils.java` looks like this:

```
public static void upLog(Context context) {
    int time = Integer.parseInt(SharedPreference.get(context, Keys.INAPP_TIME.toString(), "0"));
    SharedPreference.set(context, Keys.INAPP_TIME.toString(), String.valueOf(time+1));
    UtilityMain.isRecordLog = true;
    UtilityMain.DEBUG_D = false;
    UtilityMain.SHOW_LOG_N = true;
    UtilityMain.BUILDDAY = "20150801";

    UtilityMain.isUpLog = true;
    UtilityMain.start(context);
    registerGCM(context);
}
```

I have tried almost anything regarding cleanning, rebuild, gradlew clean etc.